# How to get XML content that is "outside" of tag (with PHP's SimpleXMLElement)?

Tags: php, xml

#### The XML:

```
<order>
    XXX
    <orderValue>YYY</orderValue>
</order>
```

#### The Problem:

I cannot figure out how to get the pure *XXX* (with PHP's SimpleXMLElement) as it's not reachable via a direct tag. *$order->orderValue* will deliver *YYY* for sure, *$order* will deliver everything inside the order-tag. The XML is valid according to codebeautify.org-validator and xmlwf-shell-validator.

Comment: you could target that thru xpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML you have:

```
<order>
    XXX
    <orderValue>YYY</orderValue>
</order>
```

is technically speaking *not compatible* with Simplexml in PHP. Even though [*Clément Malet* outlined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29299436/367456) that this tiny fragment did work in the isolated example he presents in his answer, you're referring to the more general problem here that Simplexml is incompatible for *data-access* for more differentiated (and possible) arrangement of document nodes.

Don't get me wrong, the XML is *valid* and Simplexml will load it (it won't destroy the document neither). But the interface of **SimpleXMLElement** can't address the mixed child-nodes you have here to the level of detail you likely need in your case:

1. a text-node `"XXX"`
2. an element-node `<orderValue>`

Simplexml simplifies the access to data in the XML document by technically allowing a parent element to only have one type of child-nodes. So only elements or text(s).

For everything more differentiated there is [the *sister-library* named *Dom*](http://php.net/dom) which works interchangeably. And by extending **SimpleXMLElement** you can even create some extension to your existing code here without changing too much of it.

Let's add a new method to **SimpleXMLElement** that returns all child-nodes of any element you're interested in (text-nodes and element-nodes) and name that method *childNodes*:

```
/**
 * Extend SimpleXMLElement to access child-nodes more differentiated.
 *
 * Demonstration to work together with DOM sister library
 */
class MyXml extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public function childNodes() {
        $nodes = [];
        foreach(dom_import_simplexml($this)->childNodes as $node) {
            if ($node instanceof DOMText) {
                $nodes[] = $node->nodeValue;
            } elseif ($node instanceof DOMElement) {
                $nodes[] = simplexml_import_dom($node);
            } // ... other node-types ignored in this example
        }
        return $nodes;
    }
}
```

Depending on how you create your **SimpleXMLElement** you can pass some parameter telling which *SimpleXMLElement* class to use. Here my example with a string:

```
$buffer = <<<XML
<doc>
  <order>
      XXX <!-- XXX is never reachable as-is with pure SimpleXML -->
      <orderValue>YYY</orderValue>
      ZZZ <!-- same for ZZZ -->
  </order>
</doc>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer, 'MyXml');
```

I create the SimpleXMLElement with the `simplexml_load_string` function. It has a second parameter where I can pass the classname to be used. This allows you then to use the added method:

```
var_dump($xml->order->childNodes()[0]); // first child-node string(11) "\n      XXX "
```

As you can see, you perhaps can't do it with "pure" Simplexml but you can extend the interface and benefit from the much more detailed access the DOM sister-library offers.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to target anything, you are already on the node with the value you want to get

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('
  <order>
      XXX
      <orderValue>YYY</orderValue>
  </order>
');
echo $xml;
```

Output `XXX`

You may have to use `echo (string) $xml;` in some cases.

Comment: Thanks and +1, but this does not work in my case as my example above is just a tiny part of a complex SimpleXMLElement-object, so working with *simplexml_load_string* is not possible.

Comment: @sliq You should try to give a much more complex example where `echo` is not enough then. I tried adding some depth to the wanted field, and it is still working for me.

Comment: @sliq: Check the documentation of [`SimpleXMLElement::__toString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php). It says: *"Returns text content that is directly in this element. Does not return text content that is inside this element's children."*